# finding max value on each subset

Tags: performance, algorithm, optimization, graph-algorithm

(I'm banging my head here. Let X={x1,x2,...,xn} is an integer set. Let A1,A2,...Am be the m subsets of X. For any i and j, Ai and Aj are not necessarily disjoint. Now the goal is to find the maximal value on each Ai (i=1,...,m) efficiently, with the number of operations as fewer as possible.

For example, given X={2,4,6,3,1}, and its subsets A1={2,3,1}, A2={2,6,3,1}, A3={4,2,3,1}. We need to find Max{A1}, Max{A2}, Max{A3}, respectively.

The brute-force way for finding Max{A1}, Max{A2}, Max{A3} is to scan all the elements in each Ai, and (m*d) operations are required, with m the number of subsets of X, and d the average length of the subsets {Ai} of X.

Now, I have some observations:

(1) For any set Y⊆X, max{Y}≤max{X},

For instance, since Max{X}=6 and 6 is in A2, then Max{A2}=6 can be found directly.

(2) For any two sets A and B, if A∩B is non-empty, Max{A} and Max{B} can be identified as follows:

First, we find the common parts between A and B, deonted as c=max{A∩B}.

Then, we find Max{A}=Max{Max{A-(A∩B)}, c} and Max{B}=Max{Max{B-(A∩B)}, c}.

I am not sure whether there are some other interesting obervations for find these max values.
Any ideas are warmly welcome!

My question is what if for the general case when X={x1,x2,...,xn} and there are m subsets of X, denoted as A1,A2,...Am, is there some more efficient techniques to find such max values Max{Ai} (i=1,...,m) ?

Your help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: How you know 6 is in A2? for this you should scan your matrix, instead of this extra checking you could directly find the maximum number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no method asymptotically better than brute force, assuming a typical representation of the given sets. Simply scanning through the sets to find the largest member of each requires linear time and linear time is optimal since every member of the set must be read in order to determine the maximum value.

Now if the input representation is not simply a listing of the elements in each set, than other bounds and algorithms may apply. For example, if we know the input sets are sorted and the length of the set is given as part of the input, we can obviously find the maximum elements in time linear only on the number of subsets but not on their length.

Comment: i would go with this as well. For asymptotic notation you need big O notation which your constant evaulations doesnt add any value anyways. however you want to come up with a formula related to i, j, m,n for subsets and their lengths and derive the O notation. Scanning is the best option IMO.

Comment: The point is that all elements in EACH Ai would be scanned? Is that necessary? Also, notice that |X|<< m*d, if the number of subsets {Ai} is very large. I hope there is a way to scan O(n) not O(md)

Comment: sure, how would you find the maximum if you dont. you can do some micro optimization as you did above such as single element set doesnt need to be scanned, however coming up with big O notation, you need to analyze worst case, avarage case and so on. so your micro optimizations becomes constant really.

Comment: Yeah, what I need is some practical micro optimization technqiues in the general case.

Comment: well your micro optimization wont affect the O notation. i hope u are aware of that.

Comment: You need to scan all the elements of each A_i (unless you are lucky enough to find max(X) in A_i, then you don't need to scan the rest of A_i).  Proof: the element you didn't look at could have been max(X), and without looking at it you will return the wrong answer for A_i.

Comment: Maybe the big O notation is inapproperate here, FLOPs should be used instead.

Comment: lol. are you taking algo class? dont complicate things, think simplicity. if you are fighting with it, you are prolly doing something wrong.

Comment: @DarthVader, I never think so. Simple algorithms are not simple-minded algorithms. They should be based on your intuition. What is your intution? Even big O notation is inapproperate here, that's not main issue of this optimization problem.

Comment: well, i think you are over thinking, let us know the answer as well. O notation is not based on FLOPs. If you are doing comparison, obviously you need to count the number of comparisons. FLOPs are irrelevant.

Comment: Well, that's more or less the similar thing, a measure of operations to be performed.

Answer (score 3):

If your sets are implemented in a hash (or, more generally, if you can otherwise check for the presence of a value in the set in O(1) time) you can improve on a brute-force approach.

Instead of iterating through the elements of the subset and maintaining the maximum, iterate over the elements of the parent set in descending order, checking for the presence of those elements in the subset.  The first found element is necessarily the subset's maximum.  Technically, this still takes O(n) time (n = subset carnality) in the general case, but will generally carry a great performance benefit in practice.  (If you have any data regarding the number and size of the subsets, and they favor this approach, you can improve on O(n) in the average case.)

This approach requires sorting of the parent set's elements (n log n), however, so it may only be worthwhile if the number of subsets is much greater than the carnality of the parent set.

Comment: there is no notion of hash. this is not java or c# code. hash set is implemented via hash table that s how you get O(1) look up, this is set in math. I find your answer irrelevant. Sorting the set then iterating over subsets? u losing focus there. you are doing more work.

Comment: @DarthVader It seems feasible to me that John is being asked to design an approach to solve this problem.  What I have proposed, as far as I can tell, is a reasonable solution.  I don't disagree that this exercise is on the theoretical side, but hash tables certainly have a place in CS theory.

Comment: @DarthVader, I don't think cheeken's answer irrelevant, its helpful via hash techniques.

Comment: i dont see how hash table is relevant for finding maximum, unless it s sorted hash table. and for hashing, if you are doing comparison, hashing doesnt fit in the picture.